# Title in border WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to put a border around my window.

Can I put a title within the 35px of the top?

```
<Window x:Class="LCDC.InterfazGrafica.frmModoDePago"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" FontSize="20"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Border BorderBrush="#090A9E" BorderThickness="5,35,5,5">
            <Grid>
                ...
            </Grid>
    </Border>

</Window>
```

Comment: That border can easily be overlaid by another control. I don't think there is anything in the `Border` control that will help you though.

Comment: Yes, i use WindowStyle="None"

Comment: Ummmm... ok. Not sure why thats relevant (besides removing the initial border). You can still overlay whatever you want on your *own* border.

Answer (score 0):

You can reserve 1 row of the Grid for the fake Title. You need some code behind to make the Title draggable so that user can move the window by holding mouse down on the fake Title and drag it:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#090A9E" BorderThickness="5">
    <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <TextBlock Name="tit" Text="{Binding Title, 
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="35,0,0,0">
          <TextBlock.Background>
             <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Icon, 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                   Viewport="2,2,30,30" ViewportUnits="Absolute"/>
          </TextBlock.Background>
       </TextBlock>
       <!-- other contents here, remember to put them in the second row -->
       <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

In codebehind, use this code to make the fake title draggable:

```
//in your Window constructor
InitializeComponent();
tit.MouseLeftButtonDown += (s,e) => {
   DragMove();
};
```

If you want some border around the fake Title, just wrap another Border around the `TextBlock` and just set some bottom border (because the left, right and top border are rendered by the outer Border).